# Lopez de Prado's Triple Barrier Method - do you reset the barriers on every timestep, or only when you reach a hi/lo/no barrier hit?

Tags: machine-learning

I've used de Prado's trend scanning labels but now I want to try the triple barrier method idea.

I understand the rough set up, and I understand the logic behind it. However, what I don't understand is this: Do I have an observation on every single timestep, with the label being -1/0/1 depending on which barrier is hit first? OR do I only have a new observation at the point at which a barrier was hit (so if +1 barrier was hit at t=5, my 2nd observation starts at t=5)?

Essentially, do I have "overlapping" labels or not?

I hope my question makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's only one observation. Each instance is one label. You would have a specific circumstance based on the trading domain, and you would either win, lose, or close. The time would not matter.